# Why my successor does not become my heir?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I have elective gavelkind inheritance law. Apparently, one member of my Dynasty has an STRONG own kingdom and I can nominate him as a successor. I've bought succession support enough so he is a winner (he has 7 votes, the next best candidate - 6: https://i.stack.imgur.com/reNP6.jpg). But somehow, the heir is my step-brother, with 0 votes (https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6JOC.jpg). Why is it so and how can I make  THAT KING to become my successor?

Maybe that's because I have Illegal controlled realm Inheritance? Should I just change that law? I'd try, but I play ironman and can't just try.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to say that the heir to your primary title is not the same as the heir displayed on your character view? Can you post a screenshot of what is happening here?

Comment: Posted screnshots in the topic.

Comment: My guess is that the guy you've arranged to inherit your primary title isn't eligible to play (eg. because he's Pagan and you don't have the Old Gods DLC), and so the game has picked someone from the dynasty that will inherit your best remaining title when you die. Note you'll want to go through your titles to verify that your dynastic heir will receive at least one of them, since if your dynastic heir is unlanded (as he is now) it's game over.

Comment: I indeed don't have Old Gods DFC. Is he a Pagan? No, he is an Orthodox (https://i.imgur.com/yxoFOmA.jpg), same as myself (https://i.imgur.com/D506JXC.jpg). Details of inheritance of my current heir don't matter as I'm not going to give him inherit... Worst case, I'll chose another successor. But, I'd love my successor to be a king of Denmark...

Comment: It was just an example. Normally your dynastic heir is the person in your dynasty inheriting your primary title. There isn't enough information to determine why this isn't the case.

Comment: Elective Gavelkind is known dividing titles, not consolodating them. I think that's the issue here. Is there any chance you can upload the save file; I want to try a few things before I answer.

Comment: Here you go: http://vfm.1gb.ru/ck2/Ironman_Kievan_Rus.ck2
@Studoku: any chance we can connect and chat about this? I'm also curious on how to 'inherit' Croatia... have some ideas, but would chat with another player

Comment: Unless you find workaround for current problem, I'm going to nominate Alexei Iliyaovich as a successor (he is 2nd in voting now and quiet good), marry his son on my daughter - she is going to inherit Croatia at some point. As Croatia is Agnatic-Cognatic Primogeniture thier son should inherit both Rus and Croatia. I just need to make sure that he will get elected... Thoughts?

Comment: @Budda Sounds good- bear in mind that you'll probably have claims on everything involved, so a few wars should be enough to unite everything.